# Fixed scroll div after certain height and then stops after reach other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As the title suggest, I am making a div with a **fixed** attributes then stops when the user reaches a certain point scrolling.

Below is a GIF sample of the event i'm trying to replicate.

[http://i.imgur.com/wCXAOwW.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/wCXAOwW.gifv)

and here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e1u4rqtk/2/

```
var navWrap = $('#cont'),
  nav = $('cont'),
  startPosition = navWrap.offset().top,
  stopPosition = $('#stop').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  //stick nav to top of page
  var y = $(this).scrollTop()

  if (y > startPosition) {
    nav.addClass('sticky');
    if (y > stopPosition) {
      nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
    } else {
      nav.css('top', 0);
    }
  } else {
    nav.removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

But its not properly working. any idea what did i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript for that, you can use `position: sticky`

HTML: (you don't need those extra divs)

```
<div class="d" id="fixedscroll">
  <img src="https://ormuco.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Large-Rectangle-336-x-280-Google-Ads-1-1-336x250.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d {
  background-color: #FFF000;
  width: 336px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#fixedscroll img {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Check it working https://jsfiddle.net/w9n2ubmg/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Check the compatibility table on the MDN link, you need the - webkit- prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky` for newer version of browser, but in case you want your website work under IE/Edge 15, check out this example.

```js
$(function(){

 $("#adArea").css("min-height", $("#adArea").height());
 
 var stopPos = $("#ad").offset().top;
 var contPost = $("#adArea").next().offset().top - $("#ad").height();
 
 $(document).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  
  if(scrollTop >= stopPos){
   if(!$("#ad").hasClass("sticky")) $("#ad").addClass("sticky");
   
   if(scrollTop >= contPost){
    $("#ad").css("top", contPost - scrollTop);
   }else{
    $("#ad").css("top", 0);
   }
   
  }else{
   
   if($("#ad").hasClass("sticky")) $("#ad").removeClass("sticky");
  }
  
 });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.block {
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#stop {
  border:1px solid blue;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  }

#stop{
  display:block;
}

#ad {
 width: 336px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #000;
}

#adContainer {
 padding: 50px 0px 300px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>

  <div id="adArea">
 <div id="adContainer">
  <div id="ad"></div>
 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
  <div class="block" ></div>
</div>
```